# Using react api context alongside react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with passing context to route. I get an error when i click a link that goes to my component where context was passed from App component. Below is that component with App (only one import just to show where Context is coming from):

App.js

```
import { Context } from './Context';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       cryptolist: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?structure=array')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({
        cryptolist: json.data
      }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
          <Userlist />
        </Context.Provider>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Userlist.js ( should be cryptolist or something )

```
import { Context } from '.././Context'



export default class Userlist extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Context.Consumer>
          {(context) => context.cryptolist.map(el => {
              return (
                  <div>
                      <h2>{el.name}</h2>
                      <h5>{el.symbol}</h5>
                      <h3>{el.quotes.USD.price}</h3>
                  </div>
              )
          })}
        </Context.Consumer>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```

Context.js

```
import React from 'react';

export const Context = React.createContext();
```

Everything works just fine here untill i wanted to make a menu that links to this component.

```
import React from "react";
import { slide as Slider } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Main from './main';
import Userlist from './userlist';



export default class Menu extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <Router>
        <div className="bg-navy w-100 h-100">
          <Slider width={ 180 } isOpen={ false }>
            <Link className="menu-item" to="/main">Home</Link>
            <Link className="menu-item" to="/crypto">About</Link>
          </Slider>
             <Switch>
                <Route path="/main" component={Main} />
                <Route path="/crypto" component={Userlist} />
             </Switch>
          </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

When i click a link to component Userlist i get an error thats cryptolist is not defined. I get it that Userlist can't see a context after clicking link to it. How to pass it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the routes in the `Menu` component. Is this really you want? Though, I don't know how this slide thingy works. Maybe this is the way you want to go. I think your problem occurs because your `Menu` component is not wrapped by the provider. Try like this:

```
<Context.Provider value={this.state}>
    <Menu />
    <Userlist />
</Context.Provider
```

Comment: It looks like its working. Thought theres much more coding to do. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If you consider accepting one of the answers here then this question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Menu` component will call `Userlist` but as it is out the Provider the context doesn’t exist! 
Replace `Userlist` in `Context.Provider` by `Menu` and all will be fine.